# Movie fades in through black

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to fade in a movie. Problem is it doesn't cross-dissolve in, but fades through black for some reason. I have the first frame of the movie as an UIIMageView on screen, and when the movie starts playing the screen darkens for a while. I would expect the transition to be invisible.

An example project can be downloaded here:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/2u9e5o

Thanx in advance
Nir.

Comment: have you been able to solve this? I have the same issue.. I have tried adding an image above the video and also below the video, but seems that nothing works.. :(

Comment: This question is similar, and answers the question, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216021/mpmovieplayercontroller-causes-flash-of-black-at-start-of-video

Answer (score 0):

Force your instance of `MPMoviePlayerController` to use a transparent view.

```
moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```