# How to Play a Video During Application Launch

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to know how to play a video while my app is loading, then navigate to next page in an ios app, using a `MPMoviePlayerController`. I am loading the video in the `viewDidLoad`. How can I to move to the next page after the video has finished?

Sample Code Here:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      NSLog(@"Welcome to Home Page");
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-image-new.png"]];

      NSBundle * bundle =[NSBundle mainBundle];
      NSString * moviepath = [bundle pathForResource:@"opening_ani" ofType:@"mp4"];
      NSURL * movieurl = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviepath]retain];
      MPMoviePlayerController * themovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieurl];
      themovie.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
      [self.view addSubview:themovie.view];
      [themovie play];
      [themovie setShouldAutoplay:NO];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

I am not 100% certain you can play video while the application loading. There is a great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051256/620197).

---

In your view controller above, before calling `[themovie play]`, you can register for a notification that playback finished:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

In you view controller, you will have to define a method `handleNotification:`:

```
    -(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
        if ( [notification.name isEqual:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification] ) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                          object:nil];
            // move on to your next view here
        }
    }
```

[More about notifications in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it is very useful in general. Also, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) are all the details about `MPMoviePlayer`, there is a section listing all the possible notifications and their details.