# ipad sprite/atlas animation

Tags: ios, ipad, animation

I have an iPad app, where I need an animation full screen - running in a transparent UIView.

This animation is running every time the user is winning.

The question is, would you go for a sprite animation with a very large image as the source or would you go for a small video clip?

Remember that it has to be transparent - it is starts floating around.

Any input regarding directions is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sprite, loading a movie each time user wins is much more expensive than simply showing a sprite.

Besides, to show a video with transparent background you will have to iterato throught all player controller subviews and change `backgroundColor` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4372507/529363)

Comment: iOS does not support transparent playback for video clips out of the box. There are some projects trying to overcome that limitation but those generally use their own codec/s.

Comment: Thank you, the animation is just having 20 stars floating around - what if that is just 20 layers on a UIView. Sprite vs. layers? Just looking for good practice...